# Flickr JSON parsing error

Tags: java, json, flickr

I have written this code to retrieve the photos from flickr. But when I run the program it shows this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException: JSONObject["photo"] not found.
```

And this is source code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JSONException {

    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=********&format=json&nojsoncallback=1&per_page=1&text=MatrixMovie");


    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    String responseBody = httpClient.execute(httpget, responseHandler);

    System.out.println(responseBody);


    JSONObject jo2 = new JSONObject(responseBody);
    System.out.println(jo2);
    JSONArray jarray = jo2.getJSONArray("photo");
    System.out.println(jarray);

    for(int i=0; i<jarray.length(); i++)
    {

        JSONObject jobject = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
        //System.out.println(jobject.getString("id"));
        System.out.println(jobject.getString("owner"));
    }

}

}
```

This is the response I am getting from flickr.

```
{"photos":{"page":1,"pages":9,"perpage":1,"total":"9",
"photo": 
[{"id":"5589016310",
"owner":"61369554@N03",
"secret":"eb2bf0f940",
"server":"5293",
"farm":6,
"title":"MatrixMovie-GoldenAwake",
"ispublic":1,
"isfriend":0,
"isfamily":0}]},
"stat":"ok"}
```

But not sure why its not getting "photo" array. Can anyone please help me with this.

Thank you.

Comment: did you check if the flickr json response includes a `['photo']` key? Your error suggests it doesn't - not at the level of the structure you're checking.

Comment: Hi, thank you for you response. I have added the json response as well. So far I have understood the "photo" key is there.

Comment: it is, but it's under photos, eg. `$data['photos']['photo']`

Comment: So how should I get that actually ? I am sorry I just started with Json.

Comment: No idea, never done anything with java, but the flickr response is a multi-dimensional structure if that's any help, and the photos bit you want is nested at the 2nd level down.

Comment: ohh.. Thank you for the hint Marc. You were right, I was searching in root. Anyway, I have figured it out to get the second level item.

Answer (score 0):

To call photos you should, first call another object as photos and then within that object, call array photo!
like this:

```
JSONObject jo3 = jo2.getJSONObject("photos");
JSONArray jarray=jo3.getJSONArray("photo");
```

I checked and this works!
hope it helps :)